# Get custom attribute for parameter when model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-binding

I've seen a lot of similar posts on this, but haven't found the answer specific to controller `parameters`.

I've written a custom attribute called `AliasAttribute` that allows me to define aliases for parameters during model binding. So for example if I have: `public JsonResult EmailCheck(string email)` on the server and I want the `email` parameter to be bound to fields named *PrimaryEmail* or *SomeCrazyEmail* I can "map" this using the aliasattribute like this: `public JsonResult EmailCheck([Alias(Suffix = "Email")]string email)`.

**The problem:** In my custom model binder I can't get a hold of the `AliasAttribute` class applied to the `email` parameter. It always returns null.
I've seen  what the *DefaultModelBinder* class is doing to get the *BindAttribute* in reflector and its the same but doesn't work for me.

**Question:** How do I get this attribute during binding?

AliasModelBinder:

```
public class AliasModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public static ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type type)
    {
        return new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type).GetTypeDescriptor(type);
    }

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        var descriptor = GetTypeDescriptor(bindingContext.ModelType);
        /*************************/
        // this next statement returns null!
        /*************************/
        AliasAttribute attr = (AliasAttribute)descriptor.GetAttributes()[typeof(AliasAttribute)];

        if (attr == null)
            return null;

        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        foreach (var key in request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Prefix) == false)
            {
                if (key.StartsWith(attr.Prefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Suffix) == false)
                    {
                        if (key.EndsWith(attr.Suffix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return request.Form.Get(key);
                        }
                    }
                    return request.Form.Get(key);
                }
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Suffix) == false)
            {
                if (key.EndsWith(attr.Suffix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return request.Form.Get(key);
                }
            }
            if (attr.HasIncludes)
            {
                foreach (var include in attr.InlcludeSplit)
                {
                    if (key.Equals(include, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return request.Form.Get(include);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

AliasAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AliasAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string _include;
    private string[] _inlcludeSplit = new string[0];

    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Include
    {
        get
        {
            return _include;
        }
        set
        {
            _include = value;
            _inlcludeSplit = SplitString(_include);
        }
    }
    public string[] InlcludeSplit
    {
        get
        {
            return _inlcludeSplit;
        }
    }
    public bool HasIncludes { get { return InlcludeSplit.Length > 0; } }


    internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        {
            return new string[0];
        }
        return (from piece in original.Split(new char[] { ',' })
                let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                select trimmed).ToArray<string>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public JsonResult EmailCheck([ModelBinder(typeof(AliasModelBinder)), Alias(Suffix = "Email")]string email)
{
    // email will be assigned to any field suffixed with "Email". e.g. PrimaryEmail, SecondaryEmail and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up on this and then stumbled across the [Action Parameter Alias](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/adding-an-alias-to-an-action-parameter-for-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc/) code base that will probably allow me to do this. It's not as flexible as what I started out to write but probably can be modified to allow wild cards.

Answer (score 0):

what I did was make my attribute subclass `System.Web.Mvc.CustomModelBinderAttribute` which then allows you to return a  version of your custom model binder modified with the aliases.

example:

```
public class AliasAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public AliasAttribute()
    {
    }

    public AliasAttribute( string alias )
    {
        Alias = alias;
    }

    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        var binder = new AliasModelBinder();

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( Alias ) )
            binder.Alias = Alias;

        return binder;
    }
}
```

which then allows this usage:

```
public ActionResult Edit( [Alias( "somethingElse" )] string email )
{
    // ...
}
```